# Socket.io : How to handle/manage multiple clients requests and responses?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am very eager to integrate Socket.io to my node.js project, but I have some confusions on how to properly use socket.io. I have been looking through documentations and tutorials, but I have not been able to understand some concepts on how socket.io works.

The scenario I have in mind is the following:

- There are multiple clients C1, C2, ..., Cn
- Clients emit request to the server R1,...,Rn
- Server receives request, does data processing
- When data-processing is complete, Server emits response to clients Rs1, .., Rs2

The confusion I have in this scenario is that, when the server has finished data processing it emits the response in the following way:

```
// server listens for request from client
socket.on('request_from_client', function(data){
    // user data and request_type is stored in the data variable
    var user = data.user.id
    var action = data.action

    // server does data processing 
    do_some_action(..., function(rData){
        // when the processing is completed, the response data is emitted as a response_event
        // The problem is here, how to make sure that the response data goes to the right client
        socket.emit('response_to_client', rData)
    })
})
```

But here I have NOT defined which client I am sending the response to!

- How does socket.io handle this ?
- How does socket.io make sure that: response Rs1 is sent to C1 ?
- What is making sure that: response Rs1 is not sent to C2 ?

I hope I have well explained my doubts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instance of the `socket` object corresponds to a client connection. So every message you emit from that instance is send to the client that opened that socket connection. Remember that upon the `connection` event you get (through the onDone callback) the socket connection object. This event triggers everytime a client connects to the socket.io server.

If you want to send a message to all clients you can use
`io.sockets.emit("message-to-all-clients")`

and if you want to send an event to every client apart the one that emits the event
`socket.broadcast.emit("message-to-all-other-clients");`

Comment: oh! I finally get it! Thank you. This was the confusion I had in my head, I was thinking that the socket object was a "global channel" in which clients can connect. But now it makes sense, that on every connection, a "new channel" is created.